# How can I install dlib for python 3.6 on windows 10?

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

I am trying to install dlib for python 3.6 using 'pip install dlib'
however I am getting the following error,
[dlib installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgCuj.png)

I am new to python and working on a project for school, I need dlib in order to run a program that was provided. I have installed CMake and added it to PATH.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we wants error message to be in the question post **as text**, not linked as *image*. Please, edit your question and add textual representation of the error message. You may format it as a code (`Ctrl+K` or `{}` button while text is selected).

Answer (score 0):

You can [download](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/) the appropriate wheel package and pip install it, or the .gz file and run python setup.py install though you will need CMAKE installed